# How to delete cucumber html reports folder before every run in cypress?

Tags: automation, cypress, reporting

I am using below command -

```
"scripts":{
"pretest": "npm run clean:reports",
"clean:reports":"(if exist cypress\\reports (rmdir /Q /S cypress\\reports)) && mkdir cypress\\reports && mkdir cypress\\reports\\mocha  &&  mkdir cypress\\reports\\mochareports",
"test:headed": "npx cypress run --spec cypress\\integration\\Features\\JobExecution.feature --browser chrome || npm run posttest"
}
```

Problem is :

1. It is not deleting existing reports
2. If I run same feature file again then it does not generates new report